# Which is the correct way to develop a multilingual website on C# .NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, multilingual

We have developed a web application that initially was thought to be only in one language, however now I'm being required to make it multi-lingual, the thing is I don't know where to start.

Is there any advice or text you may refer me to?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net provides a lot of functionality in it's System.Globalisation namespace, use that for displaying dates & numbers in local cultures. You can use resource files (.resx) to store your strings in the various languages you want to support. I would check out this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx